# How to rename the coefficients in the summary() of a lm in R?

Tags: r, rename, lm, coefficients

I have many interaction terms, and I want to have the name of these coefficients, which will be output to LaTeX, not be so cumbersome.

I do not want to generate all the interactions in my data frame beforehand, that is a big nuisance.

Comment: This is pretty broad; there are lots of tools for converting lm object output to LaTeX and formatting it in various ways. You might be more likely to get a response if you look into some of them and ask a question about how to use one of them in a specific context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if you just mean change the names, but if so this is how you do that.

```
a <- runif(100,0,100)
b <- 3*a+runif(100,0,50)
c <- 4*a+runif(100,0,60)
fit <- lm(a~b+c)
names(fit$coefficients) <- c('bob','sally','sue')
summary(fit)
#    Call:
#lm(formula = a ~ b + c)
#
#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-5.8876 -2.0380  0.0111  1.6112  6.4377 
#
#Coefficients:
#      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#bob   -8.72283    0.68552  -12.72   <2e-16 ***
#sally  0.15337    0.01484   10.33   <2e-16 ***
#sue    0.13740    0.01110   12.38   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 2.945 on 97 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9893,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9891 
#F-statistic:  4472 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I have interactions..

Comment: How can I get this to work with felm?